# How do I configure git to create files with the right permissions?

Tags: wordpress, git, file-permissions

I have a git repo that includes submodules for wordpress and a wordpress theme. I am trying to configure this so that I can run "git pull" on the server whenever there is a change, to update the files from the repo. The problem I am having is that after I do a git pull, I end up with a 500 error on the front end and my server logs saying "file is writeable by group". Basically, I need all of the files to have the permissions of "0755" and to stay that way after I update them with git. How can I set this up correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the documentation on `filemode`. In your repository under .git/, the config file has a section starting with [core]. If you set filemode to FALSE (or zero, I can't quite recall), it will stop git from changing permissions on any of the files. Then, you can just update them to the right permission and leave them alone.

Note that you could run into other permissions errors if you are having `git` run as a separate user (we do this with a `git` user who runs automated updates). Just something to be aware of as you set things up.